# Using freePBX as a sip client

Tags: sip, freepbx

I'm trying to find a way of setting up freePBX to somehow use an external sip account (username, password and domain) and not a trunk to make inbound and outbound calls. I was wondering if anyone knew if this was possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out it is possible. a link using asterisk as a sip client is available [here][1] Which can be easily adapted for the freepbx gui.